# Create Theme Error in Vite Application using the MaterialUI Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, vite, react-context

I am developing an application and received the error Uncaught 'TypeError: createTheme_default is not a function'.

I read a few solutions online where they mentioned that I have to wrap my main app element in ThemeProvider Tag and also a CSSBaseline tag. Both of which I had done previously.

Also I tried importing the Create Theme from styles instead of material which still did not work.

It was working fine previously but it started showing this error.

Here is a drive link with the entire build: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nDwgWovNqtP5FrD8DsvFy8e5kWq6urts/view?usp=sharing

Edit:

Apparently the issue started when I tried using the Mini variant Drawer in Material UI. It persists even after I remove the component, but fixes itself once I force re-install npm.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use only this kind of import ?

import { XXX } from '@mui/material';

instead of

import XXX from '@mui/material/XXX';

Also you can check that you have
"module": "ES6",
in your tsconfig file

I had this kind of error too and for me it worked.

Comment: I checked both and it still shows the same error.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Selena Mallet